# Python regular expression to find pattern that is outside specific HTML tags

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to get all occurrences of the pattern `!\d+` that are not between specific HTML tags.

Example input (available on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/81rUtU/1)):

```
bla bla !1234 abcd <pre> every occurrence here should be ignored !12345 but it is not </pre> here should be captured !54321 but <code><pre> here it should be again ignored !76453 </pre></code> and here again captured !123456
```

I tried this RE:

```py
(?:<(?P<tag>code|pre)>.*?<\/(?P=tag)>)?(?!<(code|pre)>)*!(\d+)
```

The logic is this:

- `(?:<(?P<tag>code|pre)>.*?</(?P=tag)>)?`: capture all text between the relevant tags in the first part of the RE, so that if the pattern appears between the tags, it will be consumed by this RE
- `(?!<(code|pre)>)*`: Make sure there are no other opening tags between the first part of the RE and the required pattern
- `!(\d+)`: Match the pattern and grab the number

This does not seem to work, and I don't quite understand why. Numbers between tags are still matched.
Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Obligatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2871518

Comment: _regular expression to find pattern that is outside specific HTML tags_ Are we really still doing this?

Comment: I think I found a solution: `(?:<(pre|code)>.*?</\1>|!(\d+))` seems to do it. The idea is to use an "or" expression to capture all text between the required tags, and the `!\d+` pattern will only match if it is not enclosed in the tags.
@Toto: The suggested post does not seem to answer my regex question. It suggests several other HTML parsing methods. As explained in another comment in this post, I was asking specifically about a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to write a regex that handles html. You could let an html parser do what it does best and just use regex on the data elements. This will do well as long as the desired data itself doesn't have markup (e.g., `!12<b>34</b>`)

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import re

class HTMLTagFilteredFinder(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.ignoring_children = 0
        self.found_strings = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag in ('code', 'pre'):
            self.ignoring_children += 1

    def handle_endtag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag in ('code', 'pre'):
            self.ignoring_children -= 1

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if not self.ignoring_children:
            self.found_strings.extend(re.findall(r"!\d+", data))
```

Comment: You're making the answer hard to take seriously if you start with a falsehood. It's definitely not impossible to write a regex that handles html - certainly not in a simple case as the OP's. I do agree that using an html parser is probably better in almost every way, but that doesn't need a false fact as an opener.

Comment: @Grismar downgraded to "difficult".

Comment: I am currently trying to find a regex solution to this problem before I resort to other solutions. Obviously implementing this is not difficult, but I have a very neat implementation in place to solve a specific problem that this regex would complete. Therefore I first prefer to understand what it is I am missing with the regex in the opening post before I decide how to proceed. Also I would learn more by understanding this regex question than by abandoning it.

Comment: @YoelEinhoren - It is an interesting challenge. Good luck!